# Colorings of a special graph

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, solution-verification, coloring

> There is a graph $G$ whose set of vertices is $V(G) = \{ 1 \dots nm \}$ and there is an edge between $a,b$ only iff $a - b \equiv 0 \mod m$, where $a,b \in \{ 1 \dots nm \}$ for $n, m \in \mathbb{N}$. Find the chromatic polynomial of this graph and its chromatic number.

I have been able to obtain it, but I want to be sure that my question is right. Here is my attempt:

There are up to $m$ equivalence classes (in this case, remainders when dividing by $m$). Therefore, there are $m$ connected components of this graph, independent between them. Besides, since $a,b \in \{ 1 \dots nm \}$, each of this equivalence classes contains $n$ elements, (this is, every component of the graph has $n$ vertex), and since this equivalence relation is obviously transitive, each of those vertices are connected with each other, this is, there are $m$ independent $K_n$'s, where $K_n$ is the complete graph of $n$ vertices. Therefore, the chromatic polynomial of $G$ is $P_G(x) = (P_{K_n}(x))^m$, where the last expression is the chromatic polynomial of the complete graph of $n$ vertex. The chromatic number is therefore $ \chi(G) = n$. Is this the correct answer?

Comment: I know but, is my chromatic polynomial correct? I guess that it is, but I would like a confirmation

Comment: Seems correct to me.